# Understanding the Kauffman bracket

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

"It follows easily from the bracket skein relation that a closed curve must count for a factor $\delta = −A^2 − A^{−2}$"

Given the skein relation $< \times>=A<\, )(\, > + A^{-1}< \,  \asymp \, >$, I don't understand how they have gotten this result. Can anyone explain?

Also, this quote is from the notes at https://math.berkeley.edu/~vfr/jonesakl.pdf

Comment: Have you looked at what Jones does on page 14? It is very similar to that.

Comment: Oh, so is the idea to then go from the result of the Jones polynomial to the Krauffman bracket. Can you do it without requiring the definition and axioms of the Jones polynomial?

Comment: I think that Severin gives a better idea than mine.  I would check *The Knot Book* by Colin Adams.  Page 149 is where Colin explains this.

Answer (score 0):

This quantity is choosen in such a way that the Kauffman bracket is invariant under the second Reidemeister move. I does not follow from the skein relation alone.

Comment: Even then though, i don't seem how it follows given we don't know the bracket for any loop.
I assumed the idea was to consider a knot that only differs to the circle by a second or third Reidemeister move and then apply the skein relation to but then you end up with brackets of two circles, and we don't know anything about how to write that in terms of a bracket of a single circle.